# Is this a deathstalker?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I caught a scorpion in my house and wondering if it is a deathstalker? This was caught in Central Asia Northern Tajikistan.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not a "Deathstalker". The members of the Genus Leiurus are what are commonly referred to as the "Deathstalkers". I do not like using vernacular or common names as they can be too broad in iverlap for multiple species and so to avoid confusion and for clarity utilize Genus and where can be determined species and subspecies. The scorpion you found appears to be a member of the Genus Mesobuthus. While superficially similiar to Leiurus sp., the pedipalps in Mesobuthus are shorter and more bulbous...among several other features.

In 2018 there was a good paper on Mesobuthids in that region. A quick google scholar search should provide you sites for the paper to be viewed at.

- Revision of the Mesobuthus caucasicus Complex from Central Asia, with Descriptions of Six New Species (Scorpiones: Buthidae)

Comment: I am not that familiar with types or some terminologies you specified in your answer. Is it a deathstalker?

Comment: @Dilshod No.  [Deathstalkers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deathstalker) are members of the Leiurus genus (as RCampbell says), which is a different genus from [Mesobuthus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mesobuthus)

Comment: Dilshod, sorry for any confusion. I shy away from use of common names as many times they are apied to multiple species or multiple Genera. I posted with the Genus of the scorpion you found so you could further investigate avenues of identification for Mesobuthids of your region.

Comment: @RCampbell, your answer would be improved by editing the question to include the useful information in these comments.  @Punintended seems to provide a good direct answer, so maybe add something like this`No. Deathstalkers are members of the Leiurus genus. I shy away from using common names as many times they are applied to multiple species or multiple Genera.`